# Magento multistore missing settings for shipping

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

I would like to setting shipping for multistore but settings are missing. For default configuration I have all settings but when I choose one store the settings are not there. I have only Title, Method Name and Displayed error Message. The problem is because I wish to set different shipping for different store. Foe example : for one store that possible free shipping and table rates for other store only table rates (without free shipping). Can you help me how I can add others fields for setting?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `system.xml` of the shipping module and check the fields that have `show_in_website` and `show_in_store` set to 0. Set them to 1 and they will show at website level or store view level.

Answer (score 0):

I find this file but in it I have many different setting and possibility show_in_website and show_in_store. This is all file. Which setting I must check and change?

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<!--

/**
 * Magento

 */
-->
<config>
<sections>
<shipping translate="label" module="shipping">
<label>Shipping Settings</label>
<tab>sales</tab>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>310</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<groups>
<option translate="label">
<label>Options</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<fields>
<checkout_multiple translate="label">
<label>Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</checkout_multiple>
<checkout_multiple_maximum_qty translate="label">
<label>
Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses
</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<validate>validate-number</validate>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</checkout_multiple_maximum_qty>
</fields>
</option>
<origin translate="label">
<label>Origin</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<fields>
<country_id translate="label">
<label>Country</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
<sort_order>10</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</country_id>
<region_id translate="label">
<label>Region/State</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>20</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</region_id>
<postcode translate="label">
<label>ZIP/Postal Code</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>30</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</postcode>
<city translate="label">
<label>City</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>40</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</city>
<street_line1 translate="label">
<label>Street Address</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>50</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</street_line1>
<street_line2 translate="label">
<label>Street Address Line 2</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>60</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</street_line2>
</fields>
</origin>
</groups>
</shipping>
<carriers translate="label" module="shipping">
<label>Shipping Methods</label>
<tab>sales</tab>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>320</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
<groups>
<flatrate translate="label">
<label>Flat Rate</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
<fields>
<active translate="label">
<label>Enabled</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</active>
<name translate="label">
<label>Method Name</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>3</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</name>
<price translate="label">
<label>Price</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
<sort_order>5</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</price>
<handling_type translate="label">
<label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
<sort_order>7</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</handling_type>
<handling_fee translate="label">
<label>Handling Fee</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
<sort_order>8</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</handling_fee>
<sort_order translate="label">
<label>Sort Order</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>100</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sort_order>
<title translate="label">
<label>Title</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</title>
<type translate="label">
<label>Type</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_flatrate</source_model>
<sort_order>4</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</type>
<sallowspecific translate="label">
<label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>90</sort_order>
<frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
<source_model>
adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries
</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sallowspecific>
<specificcountry translate="label">
<label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
<frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
<sort_order>91</sort_order>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</specificcountry>
<showmethod translate="label">
<label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>92</sort_order>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</showmethod>
<specificerrmsg translate="label">
<label>Displayed Error Message</label>
<frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
<sort_order>80</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</specificerrmsg>
</fields>
</flatrate>
<freeshipping translate="label">
<label>Free Shipping</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
<fields>
<active translate="label">
<label>Enabled</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</active>
<free_shipping_subtotal translate="label">
<label>Minimum Order Amount</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
<sort_order>4</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</free_shipping_subtotal>
<name translate="label">
<label>Method Name</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>3</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</name>
<sort_order translate="label">
<label>Sort Order</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>100</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sort_order>
<title translate="label">
<label>Title</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</title>
<sallowspecific translate="label">
<label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>90</sort_order>
<frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
<source_model>
adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries
</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sallowspecific>
<specificcountry translate="label">
<label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
<frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
<sort_order>91</sort_order>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</specificcountry>
<showmethod translate="label">
<label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>92</sort_order>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</showmethod>
<specificerrmsg translate="label">
<label>Displayed Error Message</label>
<frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
<sort_order>80</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</specificerrmsg>
</fields>
</freeshipping>
<tablerate translate="label">
<label>Table Rates</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
<fields>
<handling_type translate="label">
<label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
<sort_order>7</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</handling_type>
<handling_fee translate="label">
<label>Handling Fee</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
<sort_order>8</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</handling_fee>
<active translate="label">
<label>Enabled</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</active>
<condition_name translate="label">
<label>Condition</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_tablerate</source_model>
<sort_order>4</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</condition_name>
<include_virtual_price translate="label">
<label>Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<sort_order>5</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</include_virtual_price>
<export translate="label">
<label>Export</label>
<frontend_type>export</frontend_type>
<sort_order>5</sort_order>
<show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</export>
<import translate="label">
<label>Import</label>
<frontend_type>import</frontend_type>
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_shipping_tablerate</backend_model>
<sort_order>6</sort_order>
<show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</import>
<name translate="label">
<label>Method Name</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>3</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</name>
<sort_order translate="label">
<label>Sort Order</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>100</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sort_order>
<title translate="label">
<label>Title</label>
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<sort_order>2</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</title>
<sallowspecific translate="label">
<label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>90</sort_order>
<frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
<source_model>
adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries
</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sallowspecific>
<specificcountry translate="label">
<label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
<frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
<sort_order>91</sort_order>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
<can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</specificcountry>
<showmethod translate="label">
<label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<sort_order>92</sort_order>
<frontend_class>shipping-skip-hide</frontend_class>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</showmethod>
<specificerrmsg translate="label">
<label>Displayed Error Message</label>
<frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
<sort_order>80</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</specificerrmsg>
</fields>
</tablerate>
</groups>
</carriers>
</sections>
</config>
```